# Java Beans and Ajax - How to return a just a String

Tags: ajax, jakarta-ee, javabeans

I'm working with Ajax, and I'm trying to get a response from a bean method (a String that has a message). 
This is the code of my Bean:

```
//... Some Imports ...//

@ManagedBean(name = "loginBB")
@RequestScoped
public class LoginBean {
    private User standard;
    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{sessionBB}")
    private SessionBean session;

    // ... Other stuff ... //

    public String logIn() {

        return "Yes, you did it";

    }

}
```

And my form look like this:

```
<h:form id="form" prependId="false" action="#{loginBB.logIn}">
    <h:inputHidden id="viaAjax"> </h:inputHidden>
    <p:messages id="messages" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <h:outputText value="Mail:" />
        <h:inputText value="#{loginBB.user.mail}" required="true"
                         requiredMessage="Put your email" id="user" styleClass="form-control"/>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <h:outputText value="Pass:" />
        <h:inputSecret styleClass="form-control" required="true"
                            value="#{loginBB.user.password}" 
                            requiredMessage="You must enter a password" />
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <h:commandButton styleClass="btn btn-primary" value="logIn"/>
</h:form >
```

For doing the ajax I didn't use the `<f:ajax>` tag because is very limitated, so I make my own js code:

```
$(document.body).on('submit',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.post(url, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    })
});
```

When I check the log, it returns the whole page in the data var!! Even when I'm returning a String in the bean. I looked at the method of the request, and it's a POST, so that's ok.

I just wanted to recieve the string saying "Yes, you did it"

What am I doing wrong?

thanks!